# How to run pylintrc file as default when running pylint?

Tags: pylint, pylintrc

I want to always enable an extension in pyLint on my local machine, for instance the 'else-if' extension.
I tried editing the `pylintrc` file following [this](http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/technical_reference/extensions.html#pylint-extensions-check-elif) in the home directory of the project adding `load-plugins=pylint.extensions.check_elif`

When I run pylint on the file located at `tests\extensions\data\elif.py` the error messages show only when my terminal is set at the project home dir.

I also tried using the --rcfile flag, but found that it works only when the flag input is the relative path to my terminal.
I want to pylint always to load my `pylintrc` file without me being on a specific terminal directory or specifying the path related to my current path.. is it possible to set this pylintrc file to be a default when i use pylint?

I am working on pyLint project on my local machine (Windows 10).

```
pylint 2.6.0-dev1

Python  3.7.7
```

Thank you